# sql add column to results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

So Im looking to add the `itemlookupcode` to the results of a query. The `itemlookupcode` is in the item table, but the query is against a different table. Both tables have `itemdescription`, but when I do a join or left join it get duplicates.

```
select * 
from [RAPurchaseOrderTransfer] 
where QtyDifference <> 0 
and fromstoreid = 111 
and DateCreated >= dateadd(dd, -30, GETDATE())
```

Any Ideas how I can add `item.lookupcode` to the results?

Comment: what is the name of the other table?

Comment: if you have One-to-many relation you will get repitation (duplicates) of records in this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid duplicates you can perform a nested select to get the itemlookupcode.

With MySQL it would look like this (the limit 1 will return only 1):

```
(select i.itemlookupcode from item i where i.itemdescription = r.itemdescription limit 1)
```

With SQL Server it would look like this:

```
(select top 1 i.itemlookupcode from item i where i.itemdescription = r.itemdescription)
```

For example:

```
select 
r.*,
(select top 1 i.itemlookupcode from item i where i.itemdescription = r.itemdescription)
from [RAPurchaseOrderTransfer] r
where r.QtyDifference <> 0 
and r.fromstoreid = 111 
and r.DateCreated >= dateadd(dd, -30, GETDATE())
```